# Traversing inside and outside the SFTP directory/Folder and download certain .CSV file

Tags: java

I have written a code to download file from the Remote machine through SFTP and it is working fine if I provide

```
        sftpBean.downloadFile("/dd1.csv","C:\\test\\SFTP_1");
```

Filename and the directory where I want to download the file which is C drive.

My requirement is let say If I have multiple folder in side my sftproot(The folder which I shared for SFTP access) folder how can i traverse inside and outside  the folder/directory and download the  list of (for example all .CSV)files from that location.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    *****************************************************************************
    **This is the code that have logic.**

    package sftp.bean;

    import java.util.Vector;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

    //class using for sftp function
    public class SFTPBean {
        // variable for sftp channel
        private JSch mJschSession = null;
        private Session mSSHSession = null;

        // sftp channel
        private ChannelSftp mChannelSftp = null;

        // connect fucntion let connect to sftp server

        public boolean connect(String strHostAddress, int iPort,
                String strUserName, String strPassword) {
            boolean blResult = false;

            try {
                // creating a new jsch session
                this.mJschSession = new JSch();

                // set sftp server no check key when login
                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                this.mJschSession.setConfig(config);

                // creating session with user, host port
                this.mSSHSession = mJschSession.getSession(strUserName,
                        strHostAddress, iPort);

                // set password
                this.mSSHSession.setPassword(strPassword);

                // connect to host
                this.mSSHSession.connect();

                // open sftp channel
                this.mChannelSftp = (ChannelSftp) this.mSSHSession
                        .openChannel("sftp");

                // connect to sftp session
                this.mChannelSftp.connect();
                if (this.mChannelSftp != null) {
                    blResult = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return blResult;
        }

        // list file on sftp server
        public Vector<LsEntry> listFile(String strPath) {
            Vector<LsEntry> vtFile = null;

            try {
                vtFile = this.mChannelSftp.ls(strPath);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return vtFile;
        }

        // download file
        public boolean downloadFile(String strSftpFile, String strLocalFile) {
            boolean blResult = false;

            try {
                this.mChannelSftp.get(strSftpFile, strLocalFile);
                blResult = true;
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return blResult;
        }

        // upload file
        public boolean uploadFile(String strLocalFile, String strSftpFile) {
            boolean blResult = false;

            try {
                this.mChannelSftp.put(strLocalFile, strSftpFile);
                blResult = true;
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return blResult;
        }

        // close session
        public void close() {
            try {
                this.mChannelSftp.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception exp) {

            }

            try {
                this.mSSHSession.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception exp) {

            }

            this.mChannelSftp = null;
            this.mSSHSession = null;
            this.mJschSession = null;
        }
    }

*************************************************************************
**this the code having main method to run the upper code :**

package sftp.main.demo;

import java.util.Vector;

import sftp.bean.SFTPBean;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;

public class SFTPMainDemo {

    // main class let exec demo
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // now we start up run
        SFTPBean sftpBean = new SFTPBean();

        boolean blResult = sftpBean.connect("10.14.173.298", 22, "test",
                "ab123");

        if (blResult) {
            System.out.println("Connect successed");

            // now we will download file
            // blResult =
            // sftpBean.downloadFile("/dd1.csv","C:\\Work_old eclipse\\SFTP_Demo");

            if (blResult) {
                System.out.println("download successed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("u failed");
            }

            Vector<LsEntry> vtFiles = sftpBean.listFile("*.txt");

            if (vtFiles != null) {
                for (LsEntry lsEntry : vtFiles) {
                    System.out.println(lsEntry.getFilename() + "");
                    // System.out.println(lsEntry. + "");
                }
            }
            sftpBean.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connect failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your written code??

Comment: I have pasted my code for reference.